# Which functions are irrelevant?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Call a bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ *irrelevant over $\mathbb{R}$* iff for all sequences $a : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n$$ exists, call its value $\lambda$, then $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{f(n)}$$ also exists, and its limits is also $\lambda$.

(I feel slightly bad about the melodramatic title.)

> **Question.** Which bijections $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are irrelevant over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Possibly only those that differ from the identity in a finite amount of terms? Since given a converging, but not absolutely converging, succession, you can permute the terms to make it have pretty much whatever limit it wants...

Comment: It seems the relevant functions would encode the sort of permutation required to do that.

Comment: The permutation $\{2,1,4,3,6,5,\cdots\}$ would appear to preserve partial sums, no? At least, even partial sums are entirely unchanged while odd ones differ in one term only.  Similarly, I think a case could be made for any bijection which moves every element by at most a bounded amount.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando: however, the infinite permutation $(1\,2)(3\,4)(5\,6)\ldots$ is also irrelevant. You are claiming that the set of irrelevant function is $S_{\infty}$, but it looks to me that any element of $S_{\omega}$ having a decomposition in disjoint cycles of finite length does the job.

Comment: @lulu: what about $(1\,2)(3\,4\,5)(6\,7\,8\,9)\ldots$?

Comment: @Jack: Not hard to prove for those having a decomposition into cycles of *bounded* finite length; I’m not so sure about the unbounded case.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Unbounded?  Not so sure.

Comment: Neither I am, but the answer is clearly some group $G$ fulfilling $S_{\infty}<G<S_{\omega}$. Interesting question.

Comment: I agree...it's a very interesting question.

Comment: This seems to have been asked already: see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/213046/rearrangements-that-never-change-the-value-of-a-sum).